# What happens when you delete an imported cluster from Rancher UI

Tags: rancher

Sorry to ask but I can't seem to find a document regarding this. I have named my cluster 'test1' and renaming it seems not to work via rancher UI.

I just want to unimport the cluster from rancher UI and import it again with the proper name.

Just wanted to confirm that it will NOT destroy the cluster when I delete the imported cluster from UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gone from the Rancher UI, Cluster will remain intact

> If a registered cluster is deleted from the Rancher UI, the cluster is detached from Rancher, leaving it intact and accessible by the same methods that were used to access it before it was registered in Rancher.

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/faq/removing-rancher/#what-if-i-don-t-want-my-registered-cluster-managed-by-rancher